# Simple Way to Prove $\lim a^n = \infty$

Tags: calculus

Fix $a > 1$. I want to prove that
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} a^n = \infty. $$
When $a = 2$, then this follows from that $2^n \ge n$ for all $n \ge 1$, which can be proved easily by induction. However, $a^n \ge n$ is not true in general. I tried to prove that $a^n \ge n$ for all $n \ge 1/(a-1)$. The inductive step is okay but the base step is hard. What is the simplest way to prove the above? Thank you.

Comment: $a^n=\exp(n\ln(a))\geq 1+ n\ln(a)$ and $\ln(a)>0$ is a constant

Comment: Thank you. But for that idea, I have to develop the whole theory for the exponential and logarithm.

Comment: I suggest to prove Bernoulli's inequality $(1+x)^n\ge 1+xn$ which holds for $x>-1$ and non-negative integer $n$ by induction. The rest is easy.

Comment: If $0<a<1$ then $a_n$ exponentially decreases,  while for $a>1$ it exponentially increases (and is of course monotone).

Comment: There are tons of proof techniques in the link above. Try adapting them to your problem: if not, you can ask a new question. Also, [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz) is very useful at finding duplicates and similar questions.

Comment: I could prove it by Bernoulli's inequality suggested by Botnakov N. and Peter. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$x = a-1, a^n = (1 + x)^n = 1 + nx + ... \ge n x = (a-1)n.$$

Comment: Thank you. So I only have to prove $(1+x)^n \ge nx$ by induction. I will try.

Comment: I meant this way: $(1+x)^n = 1+nx+\frac{n(n-1)}2 x^2 + ... $ by binomial theorem. All terms are nonnegative and hence $(1+x)^n \ge nx$.

Comment: Well, then I have to prove the binomial theorem first. I will try that too. Thanks.

Comment: @D.L: You don't need the explicit statement of the binomial theorem in the sense that you don't need to know what the coefficients of $x^2, x^3, \ldots$ are. Just that they are nonnegative.

Comment: Oh, I see. I only need to find the coefficient of $x$. It will be much easier.

Answer (score 4):

Let $a_n := a^n$.

1. Note that $(a_n)_n$ is increasing.
2. For the sake of contradiction, assume that $(a_n)_n$ is bounded. In this case, it must be convergent. Let the limit be $A$.
3. Note that $$a_{n + 1} = a a_n.$$
   Since $(a_n)_n$ converges, we may take limit on both sides above to get $A = aA$.
4. Since $a \neq 1$, we get $A = 0$. But this is absurd since $a_n > 1$ for all $n$.
5. Thus, $(a_n)_n$ is increasing and unbounded. This finishes the proof.

Comment: Thank you. So I have to prove that $\lim a_{n+1} = \lim a_n$, and that increasing unbounded sequences diverge. Well, I think it requires quite long proof.

Comment: @D.L: Oh, if those are not things that you are allowed to take for granted, then I'll point out that I'm also using: "Monotonic + Bounded $\Rightarrow$ Convergence".

Comment: Oh, I see. It requires only the monotone convergence theorem. Thanks.